# Unable to call remote parameterized job using variable parameter in jenkins

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I am using jenkins declarative pipeline to call remote parameterized job. Following is the script :

```
    def svnRevision 

      def esmBuildVerison

      pipeline {
       agent any

      stages {
         stage('SVN Checkout') {

         steps {
            echo 'SVN Checkout'
            script {
             svnCheckout = checkout([$class: 'SubversionSCM',
                additionalCredentials: [],
                excludedCommitMessages: '', 
                excludedRegions: '', 
                excludedRevprop: '', 
                excludedUsers: '', 
                filterChangelog: false, 
                ignoreDirPropChanges: false, 
                includedRegions: '', 
                locations: [[cancelProcessOnExternalsFail: true,
                    credentialsId: 'xyz', 
                    depthOption: 'infinity', 
                    ignoreExternalsOption: true, 
                    local: '.', 
                    remote: 'svn url']],
                    quietOperation: true,
            workspaceUpdater: [$class: 'UpdateUpdater']])
            svnRevision = svnCheckout.SVN_REVISION
            echo svnRevision

            esmBuildVerison = "4.28.${BUILD_NUMBER}.${svnCheckout.SVN_REVISION}"
            echo esmBuildVerison 
            }
         }
      }

     stage('Building Code + Sonar Analysis')  {

         steps {
               //building project

         }
     }  

    stage('Calling test Smoke Suite') {
         when {
             expression {
                 return currentBuild.result != 'FAILURE'
             }
         }
         steps {
             echo 'executing smoke suite'
             triggerRemoteJob enhancedLogging: true, job: 'Smoke Suite', maxConn: 1, parameters: 'DevelopmentVersion=4.28.${BUILD_NUMBER}.${svnCheckout.SVN_REVISION}', pollInterval: 100, remoteJenkinsUrl: 'url', token: 'token', useCrumbCache: true, useJobInfoCache: true
         }
     }

}
```

Here when I am passing  4.28.${BUILD_NUMBER}.${svnCheckout.SVN_REVISION} in triggerRemoteJob parameter 'DevelopmentVersion', it is evaluated as 4.28.70.${svnCheckout.SVN_REVISION}. But I need to send the svn revision number to the remote job but triggerRemoteJob is not evaluating ${svnCheckout.SVN_REVISION}, but evaluating ${BUILD_NUMBER}.

I have tried many combinations but in vain. Any help on this will be appreciated.